# php parser grabbing ISO wbesite, to be converted to UTF8

Tags: php, parsing, utf-8

I am parsing some content from another website which i can see in the header is iso-8859-1. But the cms system which is pulling in the content is UTF8.

It gets most characters, but things like " get weird characters. Im not sure how to convert this content properly.

Can anyone help plz

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `utf8_encode($content)` and `utf8_decode($content)` to save and restore your code in and out the database.

Comment: ill give it a whirl and let you know. Thanks